# on change input trigger one time / on change ne fonctionne qu'une fois

Tags: php, jquery

I wrote this script to change the elements of a page by clicking on a input generated dynamically in **php**, but that bug. I have tried all the `change()` `delegat()`, `live ()` variants.

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="label attribute_name"><label for="<?php echo 
sanitize_title( $attribute_name ); ?>">
        <div class="alias-products">
        <div class="alias-products-wrap">                       
        <ul class="alias-product-count-2">
            <?php foreach ( $available_variations as $variation => $atts ) : 
?>
            <li id="alias-product-<?php echo substr($atts['attributes']
['attribute_conditionnement'],-1,1); ?>" class="active-selection">
                <input data-id="<?php echo substr($atts['attributes']
['attribute_conditionnement'],-1,1); ?>" type="radio" name="select-alias-
product" 
                id="alias-product-label-<?php echo 
substr($atts['attributes']['attribute_conditionnement'],-1,1); ?>" 
class="alias-product-selection" 
                value="<?php echo $atts['variation_id']; ?>">

                <label for="alias-product-label-1">
                    <div class="alias-product-image">
                        <img class="alias-default" src="<?php echo 
CSE_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . "assets/bankimages/can-big-single.svg.png" ; ?>" 
                        alt="<?php echo $atts['variation_description']; ?>">
                        <img class="alias-default-hover" src="<?php echo 
CSE_PLUGIN_DIR_URL . "assets/bankimages/can-big-single_hover.svg.png" ; ?>" 
                        alt="<?php echo $atts['variation_description']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $atts['variation_description']; ?>                  
                </label>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {

// select first by default
$('document').ready(function(){     
    $('.alias-products .alias-product-selection').first().attr('checked', 
'checked').trigger('change');
}); 

$(document).on("change", ".alias-product-selection", function(e){   
    var $target = $(e.target),
    product_id = $target.attr('data-id');
    alert(  product_id );
    $("#conditionnement").val('pack' + product_id).change();
    $('.alias-products ul li').removeClass('active-selection');
    $('#alias-product-' + product_id).addClass('active-selection');
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
  </div></label></td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: la function que sur un "li" de la classe "alias-product-selection"

Comment: english please.we can't understand this language

Comment: try .triggerHandler('change')  instead .change();

Comment: the triggerHandler doesn't worked.

Comment: When I don't use the 2nd foreach, it works fine, but I need to use the 2nd foreach.